# WPF reusable label and text box row

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styling

In my application I have a form which contains a lot of rows 
with the repeated pattern of :
Label and than a Textbox next to it.

```
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I am new to wpf but is there a way to create something like a user control which contains these two controls together ?
And each time I just add this new control and modify the Label's content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is a way and it is called UserControl. Just right click your project and select Add New Item. Then browse to add a UserControl, here is an example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label x:Name="lbl"  />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Width="100" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then for managing the content of the lable you will need a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) so that whatever is consuming your user control can bind to it (you can use regular properties too but then binding will not be possible):

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LabelContent", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string),OnLabelContentChanged));

    private static void OnLabelContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (MyUserControl) d;
        control.lbl.Content = e.NewValue;
    }

    public string LabelContent
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(LabelContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(LabelContentProperty, value);
    }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In case you do not want to use dependency properties then you will be fine with something similar to:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string LabelContent
    {
        get => lbl.Content as string;
        set => lbl.Content = value;
    }
}
```

And then just use it!

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpfApp="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <wpfApp:MyUserControl LabelContent="Hi there!"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```